# How do I make certain images display at certain screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

So what's supposed to happen is that when the site loads, it detects the size of the screen. Using  is supposed to allow me to query the width of the screen, through pixel size, and use that to decide which image I want to use. So my goal is to display a lower resolution image on the phone and the higher one on the computer. But for some reason, it keeps using the default image (lowest resolution).

here is the link for the replit in question:
https://midterm-for-ist113-19s-ce--malfetes.repl.co/home.html

I've gone over my textbook, so I'm certain that my usage of  is correct. But I'm not too familiar with HTML, so I'm not sure if I'm missing some key value.

the file names are accurate, as I've tested them just using img.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <picture>
        <source media="(max-width:480px)"
        srcset="title card resized.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width:769px)"
        srcset="title card.jpg">
        <img alt="..." src="title card resized.jpg">
      </picture>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="food.html">Food</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="map.html">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <h1>
        So, you're new to the area?
      </h1>
      <section>
        So you've just started school here at good ol' NHTI. Well you're gonna need to know your way around!
      </section>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Goal: high res image on PC, low res image on mobile.
What actually happens: default low res image displays

Comment: What's going on with that REPL link?

Comment: Also, what browser are you testing in?  It may be worth noting that [IE has no support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) for `<picture>`.

Comment: its the site in question. the image I'm referring to is the only one on the page. I haven't built out the rest of the site yet. I posted it so that it's better understood what image I'm trying to change. Also I'm using Chrome

Comment: My two cents: try putting a different image for each scenario - at this point you cannot be sure if it loads the one from the `source` or from the `img` itself. I remember that some problems arose when getting files with spaces in their names, and it required replacing the spaces in the names, with '%20'. Might be worth a try

Answer (score 0):

use **min-width**

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="http://uupload.ir/files/vvjs_hi-res.jpg">
  <img src="http://uupload.ir/files/m9a_low-res.jpg" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

the above code show low-res for screen smaller than 649px and show hi-res for screen larger than 649px.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed through deleting the spaces in the names. Thanks to @Andu_Andrici for pointing that out.